# Make a server manage several sites

Tags: nginx, wordpress, godaddy

I have bought a dedicated server from DigitalOcean, and configured `nginx`, mysql and php, its IP address is `a.b.c.d`. I have bought two domains from `GoDaddy`: `siteone.com` and `sitetwo.com`. I made a subdomain `sub.siteone.com`, it will be a `WordPress` site. I made `sub.siteone.com` forward to `a.b.c.d` in `GoDaddy`.

By following [this post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) and [this post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts), I put the WordPress files under `/var/www/sub.siteone.com/html/`. `/etc/nginx/sites-available/sub.siteone.com` contains follows:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/sub.siteone.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name sub.siteone.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

As a result, when I enter `sub.siteone.com` in a browser, it redirects to `a.b.c.d` and shows well the WordPress site.

The problem is that I want my server (`a.b.c.d`) to contain several sites (i.e., domains). So a mechanism I imagine would be `a.b.c.d/one/` contains the first domain, and `a.b.c.d/two/` contains the second domain. As a result,

- when I enter `sub.siteone.com` in a browser, the url remains the same while the content is from `a.b.c.d/one/`;
- when I enter e.g. `sub.siteone.com/photos/` in a browser, the url remains the same while the content is from `a.b.c.d/one/photos`;
- when I enter `sitetwo.com` in a browser, the url remains the same while the content is from `a.b.c.d/two/`;
- when I enter e.g. `sitetwo.com/downloads/` in a browser, the url remains the same while the content is from `a.b.c.d/two/downloads`

Could anyone tell me if this mechanism makes sense? And how could I modify the setting of nginx and GoDaddy to realise that?

Comment: Any reason ipv6only=on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this easily using server blocks in Nginx to create multiple 'virtual hosts', each with a different HTTP configuration. This works by Nginx processing your request differently depending on which URL you used to reach the server.

Put simply, to reach siteone.com you need to create a `server` block with a `server_name` value of `siteone.com`. Each server block can be in it's own file or in the same file, it doesn't really matter.

siteone.com:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.siteone.com;
    root /var/www/sub.siteone.com/html;
    # ADD ADDITIONAL SITEONE CONFIGURATION HERE
}
```

sub.siteone.com:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.siteone.com;
    root /var/www/sub.siteone.com/html;
    # ADD ADDITIONAL SUB.SITEONE CONFIGURATION HERE
}
```

sitetwo.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sitetwo.com;
    root /var/www/sitetwo.com/html;
    # ADD ADDITIONAL SITETWO CONFIGURATION HERE
}
```

This should provide the behaviour you need. It's also worth noting that you can do a lot more than use different root directories for each server, it's also useful to have different log files for each virtual host, forwarding requests and many more features.

Here's a crude example of having specific log files for sitetwo.com

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name sitetwo.com;
    root        /var/www/sitetwo.com/html;
    error_log   /var/www/sitetwo.com/logs/error.log;
    access_log  /var/www/sitetwo.com/logs/access.log;
    # ADD ADDITIONAL SITETWO CONFIGURATION HERE
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What you want is called virtual hosting. And it works much better than what you described!

Just add multiple `server` blocks with different `server_name` and `root` directories. One `server` block per domain name. Note that only one of them can be marked as `default_server` but apart from that all blocks can look identical.

The best way to do this is by creating one file per site, and then symlink each file into `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. After doing that, restart nginx with `service nginx restart`

Answer (score 1):

With Nginx, you should create as many site config files as required and simply modify the server_name and root sentences to map external domains to their content and code.

Answer (score 0):

Ben's Answer is good too , here is an alternative just for the sake of variety :
Create a server and inside it add multiple location blocks pointing to the location of your site.

server{

```
   listen  443 ssl;
   server_name dev.domainofmysite.com;

   server_tokens off;


   location /param {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
   }
   location /tparam {

     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7172;
   }
   location /dparam {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7172;
   }
```

}